# How to select multiple columns based on a condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, the columns are like this:

```
| id | position | A | B | C | D | E |
```

I'm selecting by id. If the position is '1', it should return column A, B, C.
If not, it should return column D, E

For example, if the table is:

```
| id | position | A | B | C | D | E |
|  0 |     1    | a | b | c | d | e |
|  1 |     2    | a | b | c | d | e |
```

When the query selects id=0, the result should be:

```
|  0 |    1    | a | b | c |
```

When the query selects id=2, the result should be:

```
|  1 |    2    | d | e |
```

How should I write the SQL query?

Comment: SQL queries always retrieve a static, predefined number of columns. You can't make a query to produce different columns according to the rows you selected. Alternatively, you can use dynamic SQL to assemble ad-hoc queries at runtime that can produce any combination of columns as needed.

Comment: Why not select all columns, and use client-side logic to determine which to use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a result set with a different number of columns per row, so it will have to be | 1 | 2 | d | e | NULL |.

To get what you want you can make two queries and UNION them together. Otherwise you could make a CASE statement for each column, but don’t do this if you don’t have to.

If you have any choice in the matter, I would recommend just making two queries and process the results separately.

But the UNION:

```sql
select id, position, a, b, c
from cool_table
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   and position = 1

UNION

select id, position, d, e, null
from cool_table
where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
   and position <> 1
```

Really though, this seems like you’re going “against the grain”. Perhaps some improvement can be made elsewhere that will make this unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually achieving this in a web app. I want to display different columns from my database based on the id provided by user. So I'm looking for doing this within one query.

Comment: The UNION technique will work for that (probably). Are a, b, c, d and e all the same data type? If not, you will lose that information. A better option may be to retrieve all columns and handle the difference in the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write a query to select columns according to selected rows.
but if you want specific columns you can try this:

```
SELECT id, position, A, B, C
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually achieving this in a web app. I want to display different columns from my database based on the id provided by user. So I'm looking for doing this within one query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select id, position,
if (id=0, A, D),
if (id=0, B, E),
if (id=0, C, "")
from Table1
```

It's a little inflexible but it's a start. You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d47c33/10/0

Answer (score 0):

A database query is not the place to put display logic. As others have said, a query has a fixed number of fields.

You could use `if` or `case` to null fields depending on the `position` field but it would be simpler to select all the fields, send them to the front end, and let it sort of out how to show the results.